# Alimayo Arango sculpting a head from cube

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

At https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d71CXmn8GU tutorial a cube at the very beginning is modified with "w -> subdivide smooth x 3" yields 3 1/2 rows for me from center to the outer edge/perimeter, but in the tutorial it is 2 1/2 rows of quads presented by Alimayo Arango. Why? The rest of the tutorial does not work for me as a result.  I am using v2.78 and the he used v2.71

Comment: It means your mesh if different that his when you subdivide it, if you ever added loop cuts, there's a chance you added too many.

Comment: Thank you for responding Luka ash.  I solved the issue accidentally by restarting the tutorial while leaving it in perspective mode and it turns out Alimayo left the state in User Persp.  - A. Prince

Answer (score 0):

The subtle difference is between perspective and orthographic views,  the ortho yields the four quads in view while perspective yields three between the center and the outer edge.  Alimayo usually requires ortho but in this tut, he put it in perspective.